# Get long url from any short or redirect url

Tags: react-native, redirect, short-url

I am using React native and i have some short url's or redirect urls to some other url. So i want to get destination url. So check with two libraries

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tall
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-shortener
```

None worked for me as tall is using node. And 2nd one is old and giving me an error. So anyone have a solution to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a library to do that, you can simply use `XMLHttpRequest`.

i created a snack : [snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@adgogo/06015a),

but only work with redirect URL not shorted ones like : `shorturl.at/egzG4`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: make sure you run it on your device, or on android/ios not web

Comment: hi @chikabala XMLHttpRequest is working fine but getting an error 

 ERROR  Error: Cannot open, already sending

Comment: @Rambler can u please show the error you are getting

Comment: Find the error it as i want initialize this function at top. Thanks chikabala

Comment: @Rambler you the most welcome